# How to load a component on click on a page that has no viewmodel?

Tags: knockout.js

I know `ko.applyBindings()` can take a viewmodel and an element as arguments. But I have a page with no viewmodels. I don't want to load/run the component on page load but on click because the component depends on data passed in by the click event.

Putting `ko.applyBindings()` in the click event listener works fine but is there a better way of doing this?

EDIT: 
I have a modal component that I don't want to load/run on page load but on click because the components depends on data passed in by the click event.

Putting `ko.applyBindings()` in the click event listener works fine on the first click it'll break if the modal is closed and reopened again.

```
// This runs on click

var init = function(options) {
  var viewModel = options; // options is an object

  ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.querySelector('.modal-container'));

  if (options.category) {
    ko.postbox.publish('isVisible', true);
  }
}


// The component

(function() {
  'use strict';

  var viewModel = {
    createViewModel: function() {
      var state = {
        isVisible: ko.observable(false).subscribeTo('isVisible')
      };

      state.isVisible.subscribe(function(visible) {
        if (visible) {
          // some code to open the modal
        }
      };

      return {
        state: state
      };
    }
  };

  ko.components.register('modal', {
    viewModel: viewModel,
    template: { element: 'tpl-modal' }
  });
})();


// The view
<div class="modal-container">
  <modal></modal>
</div>

<template id="tpl-modal">
  <div data-bind="visible: state.isVisible">
    Modal content
  </div>
</template>
```

Problems:

1: Can't reopen the modal, multiple bindings error.

2: `isVisible inside the component doesn't get the new value from postbox (published/triggered in the init function).

3: How to access the viewModel that get passed in in `ko.applyBindings` inside the modal component?

Answer (score 0):

`ko.applyBindings` accepts two parameters: the first is the viewmodel, and the second is the node you want to bind to. If you want to just bind the component in a certain area of your document, you should pass that element to `ko.applyBindings`

If you need to change the viewmodel applied to an element, you should use an observable viewmodel.

```
var componentVM = ko.observable();  // declared in a persistent location (not in the click handler)

// In the click handler, create your viewmodel (let's call it vm)
// Then set the observable, but only bind it the first time
if (!componentVM()) {
    // set observable and bind to node
    componentVM(vm);
    ko.applyBindnigs(componentVM, nodeToBind);
} else {
    // update observable with new vm
    componentVM(vm);
}
```

Comment: Is it ok to do `ko.applyBindings(null, ELEMENT)`?

Comment: Yes that is fine.

Comment: But generally you'd want to pass in a viewmodel. You say your component needs data that you have in your click event. So put that data into an object that you pass to `ko.applyBindings` and then your component will have access to it.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I'm launching a modal component on click. After the modal is closed and click again, `ko.applyBindings(null, ELEMENT)` will be run again. Can you tell me how to handle that please?

Comment: Can you expand the question with more detail?

Comment: Updated. I've omitted a lot of code to keep it understandable.

Comment: @chh, the simplest solution is call `ko.cleanNode(document.querySelector('.modal-container'))` before applying bindings in click handler. But it's hook.